# Computing the expected value of the number of runs in a sequence.

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose we have a sequence of 0's and 1's with $n$ 1's and $m$ 0's, all equally likely. A run is a sequence of only 1's with at least 1 one. What is the expected value for the number of runs?

The number of unique arrangements of the binary digits is given by

$$ N = \frac{(n+m)!}{n!m!} $$

with the probability of the $i^\mathrm{th}$ digit being a 1 given by

$$ \frac{nm}{(n+m)(n+m-1)} $$

How do I approach the solution?

Comment: Hint: the number of runs is the same as the number of changes from $1$ to $0$.  That is, the number of slots $i\in \{1,\cdots,n+m-1\}$ for which $s_i=1$ and $s_{i+1}=0$.  Now work with the indicator variables for those events.

Comment: Note:  not sure I follow your formulas.  The number of arrangements is just $\binom {n+m}n$.  If, say, $n=2,m=3$ your expression isn't even an integer.  Also, the probability that a randomly selected entry is a $1$ is $\frac n{n+m}$.

Comment: @lulu Sorry, I had the quotient flipped. It now always produces integers.

Comment: Ok, but the probability that a slot is a $1$ is still wrong.

Comment: Indeed; that is the probability that a slot is a `1` and its predecessor is a `0`.

Comment: the probability that a slot is 1 is just $n/(n+m)$, not $nm/(n+m)/(n+m-1)$, as other commenters have pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* What is the expected count of how often a 0 is followed by a 1, plus the expected value of the indicator that the first digit in the string is a 1?

Let $X_i$ be the indication that character $i$ in the string is a `1` and character $i-1$ is a `0`, with the special case of $X_1$ being simply the event that the first character is a `1`.   The probability given in the OP should thus read:

$$\mathsf P(X_i=1)=\begin{cases}\frac{n}{n+m}&:& i=1\\\frac{nm}{(n+m)(n+m−1)}&:& i\in\{2,..,n+m\}\\0&:& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Then the expectation we require is $\mathsf E(\sum_{i=1}^{n+m} X_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{n+m}\mathsf P(X_i=1)$, by the linearity of expectation.

---

PS: An indicator random variable is a Bernoulli random variable; realising a value of $1$ when the event happens and $0$ other wise.

$$X_i=\begin{cases} 1 & :& i\in\{2,..,n+m\}{\small\text{ and character $i$ in the string is a `1` and character $i-1$ is a `0`}}\\ 1 &:& i=1\text{ and the first character in the string is a `1`}\\0 &:& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Thus the expected value of an indicator random variable is the probability that the event happens.   $\mathsf E(X_i)=\mathsf P(X_i=1)$

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @AnthonyP Have you ever use Indicator Random Variables and the Linearity of Expectation?

Comment: No I haven't. I'm in an Introduction to Probability Theory course.

Comment: @AnthonyP Then you will probably be introduced to it soon enough. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: I've returned to this problem and can't seem to compute the expected valu.e When I compute the sum from i=1 to (n+m) of P(x_i=1) I don't get an integer?

Comment: @AnthonyP  There is no reason you should get an integer.